# How can I pass parameters in jquery to a on click function of a button dinamically created?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, parameters

long time lurker here in need of help.

I have a class named button

```
class GameButton 
{
    constructor ( id, width, height, buttonFunction, attrs )
    {
                this._id = id
        this._width = width;
        this._height = height;
        this._attrs = attrs;
                this._buttonFunction = buttonFunction
    }

    append()
    {
        $( '#gameContainer' ).append( '<img id="' + this._id + '" src="">');
        $( '#' + this._id ).css( 'top', this._top + '%' );
        $( '#' + this._id ).css( 'left', this._left + '%' );
        $( '#' + this._id ).on( 'click', this._buttonFunction );
    }
}
```

It has more attributes but whatever. When I create instances of this class they work fine as long as no parameters are needed. I am lost here and some help will save my life

```
let startGame = function( language )
{
    some awesome code here
}
let buttonStart = new GameButton( 'start', 43, 0, startGame, 'myParamValue' );
```

Thanks in advance

I tried [this](https://www.edureka.co/community/95297/jquery-s-click-pass-parameters-to-user-function)

by doing the following

```
$( '#' + this._id ).bind( 'click', this._attrs, this._buttonFunction );
```

but doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You had the right approach with the `bind` method that you mentioned.
Perhaps you didn't pick the value correctly in the passed function, since the params get bound to the `event object` and are not passed as stand-alone.
This means you will be able to locate the params under `event.data`.

I have created a sample runnable code that uses your question code as base and assuming everything else is working as intended to highlight the bind and param passing functionality.

```js
class GameButton 
{
    constructor ( id, width, height, buttonFunction, attrs )
    {
        this._id = id
        this._width = width;
        this._height = height;
        this._attrs = attrs;
        this._buttonFunction = buttonFunction
    }

    append()
    {
        $( '#gameContainer' ).append( '<img id="' + this._id + '" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1587207433549-7d796bccc6a2">');
        $( '#' + this._id ).css( 'top', this._top + '%' );
        $( '#' + this._id ).css( 'left', this._left + '%' );
        // Bind the parameters to the click event
        $( '#' + this._id ).bind( 'click', this._attrs, this._buttonFunction); 
    }
}

let startGame = function( params )
{
    if (params.target){  //Checking if the passed params is an event
        data = params.data;
        $( '#clickOutput' ).html(data);
    }
}

let buttonStart = new GameButton( 'start', 43, 0, startGame, 'myParamValue' );
buttonStart.append();
```

```css
#start {
  height: 100px;
  width: 150px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="gameContainer">
</div>
<div id="clickOutput">
</div>
```

Once you click on the image, the passed param is displayed below the image in the designated container.

Comment: @JonAcedo glad my answer helped. It would be great if you could upvote and mark my answer as accepted if it was the correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use .on() to bind click event on parent container

```
class GameButton 
{
    constructor ( id, width, height, buttonFunction, attrs )
    {
        this._id = id
        this._width = width;
        this._height = height;
        this._attrs = attrs;
        this._buttonFunction = buttonFunction

        ( '#gameContainer' ).on('click', 'img.gameButton', buttonFunction);
    }

    append()
    {
        $( '#gameContainer' ).append( '<img class="gameButton" id="' + this._id + '" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1587207433549-7d796bccc6a2">');
        $( '#' + this._id ).css( 'top', this._top + '%' );
        $( '#' + this._id ).css( 'left', this._left + '%' );
    }
}
```